# Does Firebase remove deleted data fully?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, privacy-policy

When I delete data in my Firebase project f.x in Firestore, Auth, etc. does Firebase actually delete the data from their disks or is there any backups, etc? Regarding the new privacy laws in Switzerland and the European DGPR, a precise answer and help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The best place to find more information about the data retention policies of various Firebase products is in the **Data processing information** section of the [Privacy and Security in Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/support/privacy) page.

Firestore is covered by Google Cloud's data retention policy, but I can't find that right now.